# fetch specific data from database using php

Tags: php, database, fetch

i would like to ask for an idea of how to fetch information from my database without getting everything in it. For example: i have an article that is consisted of 10 paragraphs in my database but i would only want to fetch 200 characters from it (so that i could have sustained information for my  articles preview). Thanks in advance

currently i am using this code to fetch my data but it gives me everything from the database

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblArticles Where id='".$_POST['num']."'");

    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($count>0)
            {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
                        $id=$row[0];
                        $title=$row[1];
                        $contents=$row[2];

            }
```

Comment: Use the [mysql SUBSTR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) function within the query

Comment: What if you need articles in a place and want to display more than a fragment? I think that if you select everything and use PHP`s substr you are okay, use a caching mechanism to speed things up too

Comment: Don't use `$_POST` directly in your SQL query! Escape and sanitize your data before using it in a query first!

Answer (score 0):

Try (make sure you change the field names in the SQL query to the actual field names):

```
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT id AS article_id, 
           article_title, 
           SUBSTRING(article_content, 1, 200) AS article_content 
    FROM tblArticles 
    WHERE id='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['num']) . "'");

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count>0)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result );

    $id=$row['article_id'];
    $title=$row['article_title'];
    $contents=$row['article_content'];
}
```

I've added the MySQL function `SUBSTRING()` to the SQL query. This will retrieve a partial string from a whole string. For example, `substring(field, 1, 100)`, will retrieve all the text between character 1 and character 100 from the field.

You should also avoid using `MySQL_*` functions. There not recommended for use in new code. Instead, look into PDO or MySQLi